# Display data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, graph

I have created below SPA, from which data can be displayed in a table from url and its working fine. I want to know how to display data in a graph for same url
Here is a plunker of which I have created till now
  `[Plunker]:` https://plnkr.co/edit/KdQK5P4SMynponoyAWOW?p=preview`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is very vague.. what type of graph do you want what should dates should we use to get some data.. please be precise

Comment: @Minato: Thanx for the response.. I need a multi graph from which one can select the type(pie,line,bar) of graph they need. Coming to the dates.. here I have provided an example url

Comment: Can you give me some sample data?

Comment: Here is the same data for  3 days: [{"DateTime":"20-01-2016","availability":"0",energy_counter:10, DateTime":"21-01-2016","availability":"0",energy_counter:10, DateTime":"22-01-2016","availability":"0",energy_counter:10”}]

Comment: I forked the plunk to include the chart code using [angular-chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).. here is the updated [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/RP6dEfHlDSrYqG3rWuua?p=preview), when you click submit you'll see the bar chart. all the logic is contained in `ChartCtrl` controller and `HelloPage2.html`

Comment: @Minato: Thanx a lot for the code..it helped me a lot. But after clicking on submit button I also want to include a drop down from which the user can select the type of graph and upon the selection of type, the graph has to change accordingly.

Comment: @Minato: Heii dats perfect  u r awesome Minato..Thanx a lot!!

Comment: No problem.. Glad I could be of help.. :)

Comment: The code is very experimental, not at all production.. you need to tailor the logic to your needs.

Comment: @Minato: when am trying to add pie type of graph I have changed $scope.charts = ["line","bar","pie"]; in script.js and included                `<div ng-switch-when="pie">
      <canvas  
        id="pie" 
        class="chart chart-pie" 
        chart-data="data" 
        chart-labels="labels" 
        chart-legend="true" 
        chart-series="series"
        >
      </canvas>
    </div>` in HtmlPage2.html. But when I select pie nothing is displayed. Why is this so? Where else should I change the code

Comment: The pie chart works a bit differently than the other graphs you need to format the data accordingly...

Comment: Pranitha.. I updated the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/RP6dEfHlDSrYqG3rWuua?p=preview) to include pie chart

Comment: @Minato: Thanx a lot friend..

Comment: No problem.. FYI. The code is really ajeeb. please don't use it! just use it for a reference.

Comment: @Minato: Will definitely take ur suggestion. Actually this is for the first time I am working on angularjs, will try to do my best..

Comment: Angular is very nice.. Best of luck. do your best

Comment: @Minato: Hi Minato. I tried to make the previous code as how I actually want. Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/fg4kdgSqwosxmmLWMbcs?p=preview. When am trying to add the chart.js dependency nothing is working and if I remove it, the graph part is not working and remaining is working fine. Please help me to sort it out ..

Comment: you didn't include `Chart.js` library. `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>` insert it before `angular-chart.js` here is the updated [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IDC8RjolremMHoT9n0gN?p=preview)

Comment: I am a bit busy these days.. I'll try to take some time out for this..

Comment: @Thanx a lot:) will be waiting

Comment: @Minato: could you pls provide solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018619/issue-with-angularjs-dropdown