# Issue with AngularJS Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, url, multi-select

I have created AngularJS dependable dropdowns, its working fine with static data from script file. Now how can I bind data to these dropdowns from an URL.  I don't  have a separate url for dropdowns, there is one url delivering everything.

How should I parse the data to get the required output? Iam very new to this,  Will be grateful if anyone can help!!

Comment: Can you provide me link of JSON structure from where you need to populate dropdowns?

Comment: @Ritesh Kashyap: Iam using it from a local host

Comment: There should be common key in States(country) and cities(states) to filter data based on selected values of dropdowns.

Comment: @Ritesh Kashyap: Could you pls provide a sample format for this

Comment: you can use $filter service on controller to search state and cities from given master list and create a separate list for city based on that filter and bind city drop down with that refined list on state change.

Comment: @Shailendra Singh Deol: The concept you suggested is very clear.. bt how can I implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First working Punker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/okKOeQViflRseqrOYeOY?p=preview

The problem is your question states something and your demo shows something else.

You can directly parse the JSON data on fly using angular then you don't have `ng-change` function to detect which dropdown was selected. Refer to the below code on how I'm parsing the data in `html` itself.

```
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <am-multiselect class="input-lg"
                                    template-url="multiselect.tmpl.html"
                                    ng-model="selectedcountry" ms-header="Select country" style="width:200px;"
                                    options="c.CountryName for c in table"
                                    ng-change="setState(selectedcountry)"
                                    change="selected()"></am-multiselect>



                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <am-multiselect class="input-lg" multiple="true" ms-selected="{{selectedState.length}} State(s) selected"
                                    ng-model="selectedState" ms-header="Select States"
                                    options="s.STATE for s in table"
                                    ng-change="setCity(selectedState)"
                                    template-url="multiselect.tmpl.html" style="width:500px;"
                                    change="selected()">
                    </am-multiselect>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <am-multiselect class="input-lg" multiple="true" ms-selected="{{selectedCity.length}} City(ies) selected"
                                    ng-model="selectedCity" ms-header="Select City"
                                    options="m.CityName for m in table"
                                    template-url="multiselect.tmpl.html" style="width:500px;"
                                    change="selected()"></am-multiselect>

                </div>
            </div>
```

next your second dropdown which is **STATE** doesn't trigger on change even if the scope is changed.

So use a `$watch` to see the changes to scope when it happens apply it to the **CITY**

So your js:

```
angular.module('app', ['am.multiselect']);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $filter,$window) {

    var tableData = {
      "Table": [{
        "CountryUid": 3,
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "STATE": "AndraPradesh",
        "CityId": 3,
        "CityName": "Vijayawada"
      }, {
        "CountryUid": 2,
        "CountryName": "USA",
        "STATE": "Florida",
        "CityId": 3,
        "CityName": "Tampa"
      }, {
        "CountryUid": 3,
        "CountryName": "INDIA",
        "STATE": "Assam",
        "CityId": 3,
        "CityName": "Jorhat"
      }]
    };

    var countries = [];
    var states = [];
    var cities = [];

    $scope.table = tableData.Table;
    $scope.countries = countries;
    $scope.states = states;
    $scope.cities = cities;
    $scope.selectedsite = null;
    $scope.selectedState = [];
    $scope.selectedCity = [];

    $scope.setState = function(country) {
      $scope.selectedStates = tableData.Table.filter(function(el) {
        return el.CountryName === country
      });
      $scope.selectedState = $scope.selectedStates.map(function(elm) {return elm.STATE;});
    }
    $scope.setCity = function(state) {
      selectedCity = tableData.Table.filter(function(el) {
        return el.STATE === state
      });
      $scope.selectedCity = selectedCity.map(function(elm) {return elm.CityName;});
    }
    $scope.$watch('selectedStates', function(newVal, oldVal, theScope) {
      $scope.selectedCity = newVal.map(function(elm) {return elm.CityName;});
      console.log(newVal,$scope.selectedCity);
    });
```

**PS:** The above plunker isn't very perfect you may some some minor issues which you should be able to solve.

Comment: :But the main thing I need is when I select a country I should be able to see only the states in that particular country and not the states from all countries likewise if I select a state, I should be able to see the cities in that state alone.. Above plunker selects all respective states and cities of that country but also shows list of all cities and states

Comment: simple enough just duplicate the scope of `table` and assign one scope to the constant ie, `country` and the other to the dynamic ie, `CItyName` and `STATE`   upadted plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/okKOeQViflRseqrOYeOY?p=preview

Comment: np! happy to help you. GL coding!